# Pass instance of base class into derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

In my application I have a list of objects of my base class type. Each one of the base classes can have multiple configurations (the derived class) and I've been trying to figure out how pass the base class into the derived class so I don't need to reinitialize the values every time. I know I can do it the following ways, but I'm curious if there's an easier/less clunky way since the base class in my code takes a while to initialize and has a lot of features.

Simple Example:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
protected:
    int a;
    int b;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int c, int d, Base base) : c(c), d(d) {
        this->a = base.a;
        this->b = base.b;
    }
private:
    int c;
    int d;
};
```

OR (trying to avoid this due to high overhead)

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
protected:
    int a;
    int b;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int c, int d, const Base &base) : Base(base), c(c), d(d) {}
private:
    int c;
    int d;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just implement a copy constructor for Base?

Comment: "I know I can do it the following ways" - Check again. The first one isn't even valid, and thus significantly reduces your proposed options. And the *default* copy-ctor for `Base` should be adequate. Why not just use it (and pass `base` by const-reference) ?

Comment: I'm curious how this would be implemented for passing it into the derived class. Would it look like this (in the implementation of the class) => `Base b; Derived d = b;`?

Comment: I think you're suffering from bad design decisions that aren't shown here, if you're constructing a costly `Base` from a `Derived` from a separate-yet-identical `Base`.

Comment: @DrewDormann I have a list of `Base` that can have multiple instances of `Derived` are using. I'm trying to avoid reconstructing `Base` when I initialize a `Derived`.

Comment: @WhozCraig fixed implementation 1. Made an error. Does that look ok now?

Comment: @99ProblemsAndTheyreAllCode Better. Passing `base` by const-reference would finish it. Knowing nothing else about your design/implementation, that's the route I would consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Base` has a copy constructor then you can simply use:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    Base(const Base& base) : a(base.a), b(base.b) {} // make your own or use the default
protected:
    int a;
    int b;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int c, int d, const Base& base) : Base(base), c(c), d(d) {}
private:
    int c;
    int d;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I ended up implementing

Comment: @99ProblemsAndTheyreAllCode Note this is synonymous to the *default copy constructor*. I.e. you don't need to implement it at all in this case. Removing the `Base(const Base& base)` entirely and keeping everything else as-above is synonymous, and will yield the same results.

Answer (score 0):

the two are both wrong: in Derived class you can not acess the protected member of the base class throngh a base object. To solve your problem,you can define copy construct for your base class and use it to initialize your base part of the Derived class